# 'avrdude: verification error; content mismatch' error with Arduino hardware

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm pretty sure this is a hardware issue. Just to prove my point, I loaded up the Blink script *and* the default startup file, both resulting in the same error. I'm worried I may of fried something or done something similar. I'm fine if the only solution is to buy a new Arduino, I'd just like to know what happened.

Here are is error message from both scripts:

[Startup File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anQz7.png)

[Blink Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ywgN.png)

No errors occur when compiling, but when the code is sent to the Arduino, that happens. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell you what happened without knowing what you were doing with your board before it stopped working.

This error may have **many** causes, one possibility is that you downloaded the **.org IDE**, which has a higher version number. In this case it should be sufficient to uninstall the *Arduino IDE*, then download the latest **.cc IDE** from [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) and install it. Be sure to make a backup of your *sketches* first.

Your problem may also be a *corrupt bootloader*, in which case [burning the bootloader](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard) may help.

Answer (score -2):

If u have another functioning arduino with same processer(atmega328 in my case) than burn bootloader on ur malfunctioning arduino using ur function arduino
here-https://youtu.be/oce7D72Mdwo